# PHP tagging a string whitout affecting the inside the tag

Tags: php, html, regex, tags

Here's the situation:

Everithing starts form and array and string:

```
$var = 'This is a string';

$arr = array(
'This' => '<strong title="this is string">This</strong>',
'is' => '<strong title="this is string">is</strong>'
);
```

If i do a simple str_replace to replace the key with the value in $var, you can pretty much guess it will replace even inside the title, what I want is $var in the end to be this:

```
<strong title="this is string">This</strong> <strong title="this is string">is</strong> a string
```

Can I use a simple regex? DomDoc? or it's simply a complicated algorithm?

Comment: can't use dom, since your string has no dom to begin with. it's just a string, not html. you'd have to break your original string down into parts, going longest first. e.g. `this`, `is`, `a string`, then do the replacements on those individual bits.

Answer (score 1):

in clean way, hope that helps :)

```
<?php
    define ("START_TAG", '<strong title="this is string">');
    define ("END_TAG",   '</strong>');

    // 'i' is for case insensitive, you can remove it ...
    $pattern = '#(this|is)#i';

var_dump (preg_replace ($pattern, START_TAG . '$1' . END_TAG, 'This is test'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If whitespace (this will replace multiple whitespace with a single space) is not important to you, you may use `strtok` to split the string and do replacements on each word/token:

```
$var = 'This is a string';

$arr = array(
    'This' => '<strong title="this is string">This</strong>',
    'is' => '<strong title="this is string">is</strong>'
);

$tok = strtok($var, " \n\t"); // Split on space, newline and tab

$result = array();
while ($tok !== false) {
    if (isset($arr[$tok])) {
        $result[] = $arr[$tok];
    }
    else {
        $result[] = $tok;
    }
    $tok = strtok(" \n\t");
}

echo implode(' ', $result), PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
<strong title="this is string">This</strong> <strong title="this is string">is</strong> a string
```